# IPC solutions for Python processes on POSIX compliant system

Tags: python, ipc, posix

I have two Python processes that need to communicate with each other on POSIX complaint system, as an IPC I thought that using a named pipe would be the easiest solution, however since I'm new with Python I suspect there are more options available. Anyone care to make a recommendation, besides a named pipe?

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you sticking with `named pipes`, if the system is POSIX compliant. That being said, there are plenty of options, you could, open a tcp socket and send pickled data, but performance, you would not beat shared memory/named pipe, and why look for a "new" solution if there already exists well defined working solutions?

You could also look at [this module](http://semanchuk.com/philip/posix_ipc/), seems to be using shared memory, I have not tried it but it looks like an option.